# How to send log files from AWS to Microsoft teams with Lambda Function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, urllib2, microsoft-teams

I have a scenario where I need to have a Lambda function that can pick AWS CodeBuild Logs, bundle it up into a json or txt and send this json to a particular Channel in MS teams as a file. I don't want to clutter the channel by sending the logs as inline message but as a logfile that folks in other team can download.
I have the Hook_URL for the channel.
I have been able to get this working with the below code:-

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  json_payload = {'text' : 'hello world'}
  req = requests.post(HOOK_URL, json=json_payload)
```

This works and I get a text message as "hello world" in the channel.
but when I run the below code:-

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  files = {'file': open('/tmp/logs.txt', 'rb')}
  json_payload = {'text' : 'hello world'}
  req = requests.post(HOOK_URL, files=files)
```

I don't see any files getting uploaded to MS teams.Don't worry about the file handle. I have not included the code to write into the file but the file is present with log content in "/tmp/logs.txt"

Please advise.

Comment: Could you please take a look at [sending messages to teams channel using webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using)? Let me know if this doesn't help you.

Comment: Hi @Trinetra-MSFT, I was looking at sending/uploading files to MS Teams in a channel.

Comment: You can [sent file in teams channel through Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-and-receive-files?tabs=dotnet) or using Graph API.

Comment: Do you have any other options. I almost got this to work but I think i have hit a limit with MS teams. "This message is too long to display here. Please visit the link to read the content.". I get this when I do a post with proper formatting of JSON.

Comment: Currently there is no other way except sending files through Bot

Comment: FYI: MSFT is breaking their link (surprise surprise) so the latest doc for sending and receiving files through bot is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/bots-filesv4 (v4)